# Proper method for setting childAspectRatio in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver

What is the proper way of calculating **childAspectRatio** of **SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount** in flutter. How to manage the the correct height of each view that is compatible with all devices and should work in landscape and portrait

```
GridView.builder(
    physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
    itemCount: snapshot.data.results.length,
    gridDelegate: new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
      crossAxisCount: itemCount,
      childAspectRatio: 0.501,
      mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
      crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
    ),
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return GridTile(
          child: _buildGridItem(context, snapshot.data.results[index]));
    });
```

Comment: That's pretty broad. Can you make the question more specific?

Comment: Is there a formula for something to calculate the childAspectRatio??

Comment: Can you give example for the child you need to calculate the aspect ratio for?

Comment: Just consider the gridview of items in https://45eqks401uca3p9xje465puo-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2013/09/mceclip10-1.png. How to manage it across devices.

Answer (score 5):

<sup>DISCLAIMER: This is theoretical explanation of how GridView works. Proposed solution is not designed for heavy content. Use GridView theory that I describe here to build layout that you desire.</sup>

Let me start with `crossAxisCount`, which is supposed to be interpreted as a number of columns in a table.

e.g. `crossAxisCount: 3,`

```
|  cell-1  ||  cell-2  ||  cell-3  |
------------------------------------ // new row after every 3 cells
|  cell-4  ||  cell-5  ||  cell-6  |
```

What flutter does with `crossAxisCount: N,` is tries to fit exactly `N` number of cells in a row. Hence, width of one individual cell will equal grid width divided by `N`.

e.g. `crossAxisCount: 3,` -> `cellWidth = parentWidth / 3` <sub>(pseudocode)</sub>

---

Now, what happens next is calculation of cell's height using `childAspectRatio` that your initial question is about.

e.g. `cellWidth = parentWidth / crossAxisCount` & `cellHeight = cellWidth / childAspectRatio`.

This way, you should interpret `childAspectRatio` as a ratio of every individual cell's width to its height (and vice versa).

---

I assume you noticed that [`GridView`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html) is rather limited when it comes to unusually structured layout.

In case you truly think that [`GridView`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html) is not enough for what you are trying to build - I'd recommend using other widgets that support multiple children layout. For instance, I use [`Wrap`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html) widget to display very fluid content, in which every element has its own dynamic width & height.

I am not aware of what type of layout you need, but in case of a very dynamic / fluid yet light concept you can try using [`Wrap`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html):

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context);
  return SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Wrap(
      children: List.generate(totalItemsToDisplay, (index) {
        final cellWidth = mediaQuery.size.width / 3; // Every cell's `width` will be set to 1/3 of the screen width.
        return SizedBox(
          width: cellWidth,
          // You can either use some static number for `height`, or set ratio to cellWidth.
          // Setting `height` to `null` should work too, which would make height of a cell auto-resizable according to its content.
          height: 123,
          child: ...,
        );
      })
    )
  );
}
```

However, I would not recommend using this to display large sets of data.

If your goal is to display a set of posts / articles / pictures etc., something that initially implies structured heavy content - I would recommend going with [`GridView`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html) by standardising cells height through `childAspectRatio`.

Comment: How this is standardised cells height through childAspectRatio??

Comment: @AshwinSAshok what I meant is that all cells will have one size, according to `childAspectRatio`. If you have dynamically sized elements - you might want to use `Wrap` solution that I proposed.

Comment: You have already mentioned that " Wrap : I would not recommend using this to display large sets of data." Is there a possible way to calculate the childAspectRatio.